# which tool do you use to determine if a query is using indexes?

Tags: sql

which tool do you use to determine if a query is using indexes in ANSI compliant database?

Comment: The execution plan. (`explain plan` for Oracle or `explain` for Postgres)

Comment: You have to specify dbms used, since different products have different ways to determine index usage.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you have not stated which DBMS you are using so I have given you my knowledge on this running on MSSQL 2014.

You can use the index monitoring feature to check if indexes are used by an application or not. If u set the MONITORING USAGE property for an index, you can query the v$object_usage to see if the index is being used or not. Here is an example:

```
 SQL> CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 NUMBER);
    Table created.


SQL> CREATE INDEX t1_idx ON t1(c1);
Index created.

SQL> ALTER INDEX t1_idx MONITORING USAGE;
Index altered.

SQL> SELECT table_name, index_name, monitoring, used FROM v$object_usage;
TABLE_NAME                     INDEX_NAME                     MON USE
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --- ---
T1                             T1_IDX                         YES NO

SQL> SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c1 = 1;
no rows selected

SQL> SELECT table_name, index_name, monitoring, used FROM v$object_usage;
TABLE_NAME                     INDEX_NAME                     MON USE
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --- ---
T1                             T1_IDX                         YES YES


To reset the values in the v$object_usage view, disable index monitoring and re-enable it: 

ALTER INDEX indexname NOMONITORING USAGE;
ALTER INDEX indexname MONITORING   USAGE;
```

Comment: And this is for which dbms?